# Stratum service_repository missing

Tags: stratum

Trying to get stratum working on my server.

When I start the server everything looks ok except I get this message:

```
***** Is service_repository missing? Add service_repository module to your python path!
```

Clients can connect on port 3333 but instantly get disconnected. I suspect it is to do with the error above.

I cannot seem to find any service_repository - so dont know what path to add to my PYTHONPATH?

Any ideas?